# How to completely disable MultiWindow support in LIBGDX game

Tags: android, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0, multi-window

I'm getting alot of memory allocations in my render thread and I've [traced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287679/lots-of-allocations-in-libgdx-slow-down-game-and-cause-sprite-jolts) the cause to MultiWindow support which is weird because I have **this feature disabled on my phone**. I've added to AndroidManifest the following (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111052/adding-multi-window-support-to-android-application)) code inside the application tag but with no luck, I still get unwanted memory allocations (only when I touch the screen):

```
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="false" />
<meta-data android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.multiinstance.enable"
            android:value="false" />
```

How can I completely disable the MultiWindow feature from inside the apk?

Comment: It seems to be an issue in Samsung's code, and it apparently happens regardless of whether the app claims to support multiwindow. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217001/how-to-stop-excessive-object-creation-on-samsung-phones

Comment: Yes, I only get this pb on the S4. Older samsungs dont`t have this issue as far as I've tested.