# Fastest way to access collision detection in LIBGDX - is static better?

Tags: java, performance, libgdx, scene2d

I do a lot of collision detection each frame and I use LIBGDX's `com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector` class. Would I gain any significant time performance (higher FPS) if I import the package as static and access it that way?

```
import static com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector.*;
... 
if(overlaps(circle, rectangle) { ... }
```

Or, by simply accessing the class directly each call it wouldn't make any difference at all?

```
import static com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector;
... 
if(Intersector.overlaps(circle, rectangle) { ... }
```

Comment: This probably will not make any difference.  Have you tried profiling your program to identify what the actual bottlenecks are??

Comment: I know where my bottlenecks are , I cannot solve them entirely right now , apparently there is no solution for them : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290757/how-to-completely-disable-multiwindow-support-in-libgdx-game .   So I'm trying to squeeze as much performance out of the code as I can!